# generic class inherited from NameObjectCollectionBase - make type safe 'for each' loops

Tags: .net, generics

my class - `Class GenericNameValueCollection(Of valueT) inherits from NameObjectCollectionBase`, but when I iterate a collection of this class it lets me use any object in the for each loop , I want it to check the type of object and make sure that the object is the same type as the collection, but the  `NameObjectCollectionBase  GetEnumerator` function is allowing any object type.I also tried adding  `Implements IEnumerator(Of valueT)` to my class but it is still getting the enumerator from the base class.

How can I restrict the enumerator to my generic type?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement IEnumerable instead, as that is what its looking for

Comment: works, but my enuerator is :
 Public Class ObjectEnumerator
        Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of valueT)


aand it is forcing me to implement both these in the enumerator:

ReadOnly Property Current() As valueT Implements 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of valueT).Current

and 

ReadOnly Property Current1() As Object Implements System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>;`

Sample:

```
using MyIntDict = System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int, string>;

public List<MyIntDict> GetMyList()
{
    List<MyIntDict> aoIntDic = new List<MyIntDict>();
    aoIntDic.Add(new MyIntDict(1, "Option 1"); 
    aoIntDic.Add(new MyIntDict(2, "Option 2");
    return aoIntDic;
}
```